# Add days number to string Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to add 5 days to the date however because I need a date as dd mmm yy the date has to be a string. The string part works great but as soon as I add anything to the new date value it then doesn't increment the month. Adding any later infers the number as a string.

Thanks

```
monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    const dateObj = new Date();
    const month = monthNames[dateObj.getMonth()];
    const day = String(dateObj.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    const year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    const output = + day +'\n'+ month  + '\n' + year;

    document.write(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setDate()` to add days to your date. Then you can use `toLocaleDateString()` to format your date.

```js
const addDays = (days) => {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: 'short',
    year: 'numeric'
  });
}

console.log(addDays(5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```